# Plists Loading On Simulator but Not On iPhone

Tags: objective-c, arrays, plist

I have arrays filled with strings being saved to my plists, everything runs fine on the simulator but when i load the app with my iPhone the arrays that are saved to the plists are returned null. Here is the code:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


// Get path to balance.plist in the Documents directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                     NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES
                                                     );
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"balance.plist"];
NSString *path2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"interest.plist"];
NSString *path3 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"principal.plist"];
NSString *path4 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dates.plist"];
NSString *path5 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"paymentperiods.plist"];
NSMutableArray *testArray;
NSMutableArray *interestArray;
NSMutableArray *principalArray;
NSMutableArray *dateArray;
NSMutableArray *paymentPeriods;
// Check to see if the plist exists, if not create it
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
    // If the file exists, read the array from file
    testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:balanceLabels];
    interestArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:interestLabels];
    principalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:pricipalLabels];
    dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:dateValues];
    paymentPeriods = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:paymentAmounts];

}
else
{
// If the file doesn’t exist, create an empty array
balanceLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}


[testArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
[interestArray writeToFile:path2 atomically:YES];
[principalArray writeToFile:path3 atomically:YES];
[dateArray writeToFile:path4 atomically:YES];
[paymentPeriods writeToFile:path5 atomically:YES];
```

}

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't get the code... it seems different from what you SAY wanna do - AFAICS

Comment: not sure what you mean, can you clarify? thanks.

Comment: Is `balanceLabels` (and others) arrays of labels?

Comment: balancelabels and others are properties holding the arrays of strings

Comment: @rmaddy -- why do you assume he is?

Comment: I don't get this question but I don't think thats it ^^ but I may be wrong :D

Comment: @Daij-Djan Oops - I don't know what I was thinking at the time. My mistake.

Comment: guys lets focus here, the important part of the code is where the plist  is saving to - something isn't saving right and I have no idea why - it works fine in simulator though

Answer (score 0):

So I Figured out you have to change from NSString to NSURL

```
NSURL *documentsDirectory = [NSFileManager.defaultManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                           inDomains:NSUserDomainMask].firstObject;
NSURL *path = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"balance.plist"];
NSURL *path2 = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"interest.plist"];
NSURL *path3 = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"principal.plist"];
NSURL *path4 = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"dates.plist"];
NSURL *path5 = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"paymentperiods.plist"];
NSMutableArray *testArray;
NSMutableArray *interestArray;
NSMutableArray *principalArray;
NSMutableArray *dateArray;
NSMutableArray *paymentPeriods;
// Check to see if the plist exists, if not create it
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[documentsDirectory path]])
{
    // If the file exists, read the array from file
    testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:balanceLabels];
    interestArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:interestLabels];
    principalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:pricipalLabels];
    dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:dateValues];
    paymentPeriods = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:paymentAmounts];

}
else
{
// If the file doesn’t exist, create an empty array
balanceLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}
[testArray writeToURL:path atomically:YES];
[interestArray writeToURL:path2 atomically:YES];
[principalArray writeToURL:path3 atomically:YES];
[dateArray writeToURL:path4 atomically:YES];
[paymentPeriods writeToURL:path5 atomically:YES];
```